# Scaling for Different iPhone Screens in Sprite Kit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, scaling, sprite

I am creating an iPhone game in sprite kit.  After weeks of research, I am still having trouble understanding how to properly size and implement sprites for each screen size.

I understand that these suffixes determine which image to use (depending on the aspect ratio of the screen)

@2x - 4s,5,6

@3x - 6+

I have read and tooled with different scaling modes in my view controller but had no luck and difficulty understanding them.

If I provide a background of 750x1136 (pixels) as the @2x, it will perfectly fit the iphone 6 but will be too big for the iphone 5.  If scaling is the answer, how would "sprite kit" know I provided an image for the iphone 5 that I want scaled up for the 6, or vice versa?   Is this a build setting?  Same for characters, I need iphone 6 sprites to be proportionally bigger than the iphone 5 sprites.

How would I most appropriately size and scale sprites for the different devices? (easier to discuss in terms of the backgrounds that should be the exact size of the screen)

I am expecting to create one set of sprites for each aspect ratio using the resolution of the biggest screen size.  Ex. @2x designed for iPhone 6 and scaled down for the 5 and 4s.

Answer (score 0):

The 3x, 2x and normal images are not really intended to be manipulated that way. The three images should be essentially the same image with the 3x having exactly 3 times the pixel dimensions of the normal, the 2x having double dimensions etc.

If you need to scale the scene to better fit the format of a particular device, you may need to scale that when you create the scene, the way Apple sample code does:

```
         var viewSize = self.view.bounds.size

        // On iPhone/iPod touch we want to see a similar amount of the scene as on iPad.
        // So, we set the size of the scene to be double the size of the view, which is
        // the whole screen, 3.5- or 4- inch. This effectively scales the scene to 50%.
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
            viewSize.height *= 2
            viewSize.width *= 2
        }
```

Comment: My scene is being set to the proper size of the device.  My issue is that the background/sprites are a fixed size in pixels and do not scale based on the device.  

So, it seems like you are implying I will have to check which screen size I am using and scale the sprites accordingly. (Was hoping for something that automatically does that)

Comment: Have a look at: "Customizing Image Sets for Devices
Add images to a set that are customized for display on the devices supported by your app."  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/CustomizingImageSets.html